# Raydium swap without creating Token Account

Tags: swap, raydium, token-account

My typescripts program swaps tokens but creates an account token each time.
I saw on Solscan that it is possible not to create an account. how can I do it, any advice or code? sample transaction: https://solscan.io/tx/268kSVoy8rf2qTuysWPSPkjiNHAH8ZLmV1e1Jk8N7JaYx9VUMDDXd678AZFeUiReKbiZyUqL9yTKeSzPS17BPARA

Answer (score 2):

All tokens, other than NATIVE_TOKEN (unwrapped Solana), (and perhaps Compressed NFTs), require an Associated Token Account.

The transaction you linked does indeed create and use an Associated Token Account: EnJ5PjCYLag51YcoBFwAUN9RSoiftduCxR7hCtT3Z6v3.

If the token account already exists for the receiver in question, you can use it. This function is helpful:

```
getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(connection, payer, mint, owner, allowOwnerOffCurve?, commitment?, confirmOptions?, programId?, associatedTokenProgramId?): Promise<Account>
```

[Link to Function Reference](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/functions/getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount.html#getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount)